# Looking for a viable solution to using XML file as constant data source

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking for suggestions on how to best attack my problem.

I have a web application that will utilize a database and XML file as its data source.

Updating the DB is no issue, dealing with the XML file is.

First understand the web app is a bypass to a current(and bad performing production system). So there is no flexibility there.

So in case of the XML file the following steps will need to be performed if a user adds/update/delete a field.

Pull XML file from linux server

Parse XML file into POCOs for the UI

Recreate the XML file from the POCOs with the modifications

Push XML file to the linux server

The only good thing in my favor is that I won't have very many users using this app at a given time.

Comment: This all sounds good, start coding. Does your xml file have a representation in POCO's that can be serialized and deserialized directly from the xml file?

Comment: I assume the POCO object a binary and the XML is just a wrapper of the data.  So the binary is probably UUEncoded.  So first you will have to use UUDecode to get binary.  Once you have binary it may be better to use a c++ utility to pack binary into object before going to C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking at the `DataContractSerializer` for your serialization needs.  Your objects would have to follow the same format as the XML, but there is no reason that you can't make those objects your model.  Here is an example of marking up a POCO to serialize automatically to and from XML:

```
[DataContract]
public class Account
{
    [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double Balance { get; set; }
}
```

And then you use the serialization code like this:

```
string serializedAccount = null;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account));
using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, myAccountObject);
    serializedAccount = writer.ToString();
}

// serializedAccount should look something like this:
//
// <Account Name="MyName">
//   <Balance>100</Balance>
// </Account>
//
// Each of the DataMember and DataContract attributes allow you to override
// names so that you can make them lower case, or provide a more meaningful
// name in your POCO.

Account deserializedAccount = null;
using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(serializedAccount))
{
    deserializedAccount = serializer.DeSerialize(reader) as Account;
}
```

A couple things to keep in mind:

- DataContract is an *opt in* policy.  Members are ignored unless you explicitly mark them as ignored.
- If you want to explicitly  mark a field or property as ignored, use the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.  It can be handy even just for documentation purposes.
- Nothing in the serializer prevents you from implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so all your properties can be bindable (handy for WPF)
- If your XML format is not what you want to use as a model for your UI, you still may need to map properties in one object to properties in another object.  This is still orders of magnitude easier than hand writing the XML reading/writing code yourself.

NOTE: if your server implements a proper SOAP web API, then WCF can take the WSDL and generate the bindings to the API and the objects that need to be serialized.  There's a bit more work involved if it's a REST API, but that's also supported.